# How to get Typescript to infer a specific type from an Array.map call from generic list of types?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

The following code works:

```
interface Model {
  keyFromModel: string;
  anotherKeyFromModel: number;
}
export const getKeyLoader = <T, K extends keyof T>(model: mongoose.Model<T & mongoose.Document>, key: K, one: boolean) => {
  type inputType = NonNullable<T[K]>; // this becomes type "string"
}
```

I can call it like so

```
getKeyLoader(model, "keyFromModel", true).load()
```

...and the type of K is "keyFromModel".

However I want the loaders param to accept an array of keys from the model interface.

```
export const getLoadersForModel = <T, K extends keyof T>(model: mongoose.Model<T & mongoose.Document>, loaders: K[]) => {
  const dataLoaders = loaders.map((key) => { // key is inferred as keyof T
      const test = getKeyLoader(model, key, true);
      return test;
  });
}
/// ... in getKeyLoader ...
// type inputType = NonNullable<T[K]>; // K becomes a union of all `keyof T ` and inputType becomes `any`
```

Instead the full union set of `keyof Model` type is passed to `getKeyLoader`, whereas I just want the key in that iteration of the `Array.map` call and the string literal type.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I had another wrapper function I forgot about:

```
<T>(name: string, types: string, loaders: (keyof T)[]) => {
  ...getKeyLoader(...)
}
```

I changed it to this to fix the issue:

```
<T, K extends keyof T>(name: string, types: string, loaders: K[])
```